# Javascript - passing parameters in addEventListener causing object to change?

Tags: javascript

This might be difficult to explain so please bear with me.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
  var object = this;
  (function(object, i) {
    object.array[i].addEventListener(event, function() {
      func(i)
    }, false)
  }(object, i));
}
```

The array here is a collection of HTML elements created by using query selector.

This code is held within a prototype method that is passed the parameter 'func'. The value passed for 'func' is an anonymous function.

With the code above I can successfully pass the counter 'i' back to the anonymous function.

One of the other methods, will use Javascript's parentNode function over the array of elements. Here is the problem, with the code above an error is caused saying the array element is not an object.

However when this code is used that error doesn't occur.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
  var object = this;
  (function(object, i) {
    object.array[i].addEventListener(event, func, false)
  }(object, i));
}
```

So for some reason wrapping 'func' in an anonymous function in addEventListener is changing the array element, at least it appears to be. But that doesn't seem to make sense?

Comment: Why are you naming variables in multiple scopes with the same names (i.e. object, i)?

Comment: Use `object.array[i]` instead of `object.array.[i]`

Comment: `object.array.[i]` is not valid syntax. Also, in the first example you're calling `func(i)`. In the second, it's equivalent to calling `func()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "*One of the other methods, will use Javascript's parentNode function over the array of elements*"? Please post your whole actual code.

Comment: in the first snippet, you're passing `i` to `func`, in the second snippet the event object is passed.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I'm not using array.[i]

Comment: @bergi both versions "work" is just their affect on the the objects in the array that is the problem i.e this.array[i].parentNode when used later on says undefined is not an object (when using the first version)

Comment: @Guesser Where is "later"? Please post that code that is not working!

Comment: I can't post the whole code. But there is a method that loops through the array simply doing this.array[i]=this.array[i].parentNode; which is where the error occurs.

Comment: You might want to look into how the context is bound when a DOM event handler is called (link: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler)). Accessing `this` inside the event handler bound by `addEventListener` will --- in compliant browsers --- give you the element the handler was bound to. So, `this.array[i]` will actually be `object.array[i].array[i]` and you will get an error message.

Comment: @FK82 the error is from the code above it's when the method that uses parentNode on the array is called, or is that what you mean?

Comment: @Guesser Probably :-) Just to be clear in a handler bound like  `e.addEventListener(event, function() {console.log(this)}, false)` the reference `this` will by default point to a DOM element (unless `this` was bound statically e.g. using `Function.prototype.bind`).

Comment: Not sure if this is what your are looking for for (var i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
  var object = this;
  
  object[array[i]].addEventListener('click',fun.bind(this,i),false);
}

function func(i){
  alert(i);
}

Comment: posting it as answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           (function (object,i) {

            object.array[i].addEventListener('click', 

            function(event){
            var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
            func(targetElement,i);
            }, 

            false);

            }(object,i));
```

This is what worked for me in the end, by passing the event to the dynamic function I could reference the parentNode of the clicked element as I needed.

Comment: You make it sound like software development is all about trial and error with little actual thought. If you're using any function (in this case `func`) you should know what it is - not necessarily the details, but you need to know what arguments it takes, and if you're calling it you need to supply those arguments. (And in fact, it looks like the `i` argument to `func` isn't used, so you might as well just write `func(targetElement);`.)

Comment: Sorry no, func can be any function in this case that is part of the design.

Comment: @DavidKnipe what do you mean by "You make it sound like software development is all about trial and error with little actual thought."  I'm not sure how you have come to that conclusion.

Comment: "This is what worked for me in the end" sounds like trial & error. `func` can do anything, but it must have known argument list & return type. Otherwise you can't know how to call it. Yes, there's trial & error, even with documented interface, because humans are imperfect. But in your example you should know what you're doing. Maybe you haven't matured as a developer, so I'm trying to articulate a thought pattern you should learn. But hard to explain. A more concrete example would help: could you explain the point of this exercise? Who's providing `func`, and have they told you its arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of bind here.

check this snippet

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
   var object = this;
   object[array[i]].addEventListener('click', fun.bind(this, i), f‌alse);
 }

 function func(i) {
   alert(i);
 }
```

Hope it helps